# input detection to effect variables

Tags: python

i want a given variable to turn from false to true when an input is detected
for example

```
'''examplevar = False 
inp = input()'''
```

now I just want examplevar to change from False to True when I input something to inp.

is this possible to do?

Comment: Write `examplevar = True` below `inp = input()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a lot of ways that you can do this, one of them could be to do something like

```py
exampleVar = False
inp = None
inp = input()
if inp != None:
    exampleVar = True
```

Or if you want to process multiple inputs, simply flip the value of `exampleVar`:

```py
exampleVar = False
while True:
    inp = None
    inp = input()
    if inp != None:
        exampleVar = not exampleVar
```

Comment: if my answer was useful consider to mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
examplevar = False
inp = input()
if inp:
   examplevar = True
```